# How to find first instance of HTML comment starting with <!-- ? (Python)

Tags: python, html, regex, comments, string-matching

Is there a simple way of finding the first instance of HTML comment starting with `<!--`?

I've been doing it as such:

```
for line in open('some.html'):
  if line[:4] == "<!--":
    print line
    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
itertools.ifilter(lambda x:x.startswith('<!--'), open('test')).next()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) module:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
>>> html = """
... Pineapples
... <!-- I'm a sneaky comment --> Text
... 
... Text <!-- Cabbages -->
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.find(text=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment)).strip()
I'm a sneaky comment
```